# Supervise a gen_tcp client/server

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using Phoenix framework and trying to configure a process which will connect to another server which gives me some feeds. I'm using Erlang's `gen_tcp` to do that. I want to send those feeds to clients connected with Channels later (not really that important).

I want it to be supervised, so if there is no connection to the remote resources the application won't break but wait for the connection to restore. If there is any error I would like it to be restarted by supervisor.

This is what i tried:

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.TestServer do
  use GenServer

  def start_link() do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init(_) do 
    pid = spawn run
    {:ok, pid}
  end

  def run do
    socket = _connect()
    _loop(socket)
  end

  defp _loop(socket) do

    _recv(socket) |>
    _handle_message(socket) |>
    _broadcast

    _loop socket
  end

  defp _connect do
    opts = [:binary, packet: :line, active: false, reuseaddr: true, keepalive: true]
    {:ok, socket} = :gen_tcp.connect('10.10.10.10', 1000, opts)
    socket
  end

  defp _recv(socket) do
    case :gen_tcp.recv(socket, 0) do
      {:ok, m} -> m
      {:error, _} -> raise :disconnected
    end
  end

  defp _handle_message(message, _socket) do
    # parse message and stuff like that
    String.strip message
  end

  defp _broadcast(parsed_message) do
    HelloPhoenix.Endpoint.broadcast("room:lobby", "receive", parsed_message)
  end

end
```

I also added worker to Application supervisor. This works, but when I restart connection I get errors like that (whole application crashes...):

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Mar-2016::23:53:54 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application hello_phoenix: HelloPhoenix.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: HelloPhoenix.TestServer
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (RuntimeError) :disconnected
            (hello_phoenix) lib/hello_phoenix/test_server.ex:83: HelloPhoenix.TestServer._handle_message/2
            (hello_phoenix) lib/hello_phoenix/test_server.ex:46: HelloPhoenix.TestServer._loop/1
            (hello_phoenix) lib/hello_phoenix/test_server.ex:43: HelloPhoenix.TestServer._loop/1
            (hello_phoenix) lib/hello_phoenix/test_server.ex:34: HelloPhoenix.TestServer._run/0
            (hello_phoenix) lib/hello_phoenix/test_server.ex:12: HelloPhoenix.TestServer.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

How should I approach this so it's never gonna crash / will wait for reconnect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar to this for reading a serial port before. You do not want to connect from the `init/1` callback. Instead send the process a message to connect after it's started. You also want to handle errors when connecting so the supervisor isn't restarting this server. If the port is not available this would eventually crash your entire app.

Using your code I put the following example together. I didn't get to compile or test this so YMMV. Hope this helps.

```
defmodule TcpUsage do
  use GenServer

  defmodule State do
    defstruct socket: nil
  end

  def start_link, do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])

  def init(_) do
    # try to open connection in 100ms, this could be a send or cast
    Process.send_after(self, :connect, 100)

    {:ok, %State{}}
  end

  def handle_info(:connect, %State{socket: nil} = state) do
    {:noreply, connect(state)}
  end   

  def handle_call({:recv, bytes, timeout}, _, state) do 
    case :gen_tcp.recv(state.socket, bytes, timeout) do
      {:ok, _} = ok ->
        {:reply, ok, state}
      {:error, :timeout} = timeout ->
        {:reply, timeout, state}
      {:error, _} = error ->
        {:reply, error, state}
    end
  end   

  defp connect(state) do
    opts = [:binary, packet: :line, active: false, reuseaddr: true, keepalive: true]
    # I would try to move these to your config, and pass them as args into the genserver,
    # Or load them from here with Application.get_env
    case :gen_tcp.connect('10.10.10.10', 1000, opts) do
      {:ok, socket} ->
        %{state| socket: socket}
      {:error, _} ->
        Process.send_after(self(), :connect, 5_000) # maybe do some backoff here, get the wait time from a function
        state
    end
  end
end
```

You may want to send a new `:connect` message if the socket closes to start up the reconnect loop.

You may also want to handle closing the socket in this server's `terminate` callback.

Also this module https://github.com/fishcakez/connection could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is simmilar to what I ended up with in the end actually, but thanks for all the other info, like handling terminate etc.

Comment: hey, I tried this logic (of handling messages in `handle_info` - earlier I was doing this by looping recv) and it doesn't seem to work. The code never enters this function `handle_info({:tcp, socket, message}, %State{socket: socket} = state)`. What do you think might be the issue?

Comment: So doing some further research I will edit my answer, `:gen_tcp` does not work how I thought. You do need the recv loop. I found this module: https://github.com/fishcakez/connection that does some light wrapping of `:gen_tcp` which may work in some cases.